# Java List array showing non existing folders.. Why?

Tags: java, file, hidden, directory

I am in the process of making a program, which allows you to view your file system.
I was testing it, and ran into a problem: It was saying a directory called "Documents and Settings" was on my C:\ drive, while it wasn't there.

This is how I get my file array:

```
File f = new File(path); //path being a path sent by the client, for example C:\
            if(f.isFile()){
                //TODO start downloading it.
                out.println("ERR: no dir!");
                return;
            }
            Server.log.log("System path requested: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
            File[] files = f.listFiles();
            for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
                File found = files[i];
                if(!found.exists()){
                    continue;
                }
                if(found.isDirectory()){
                    out.println("dir:" + found.getName());
                }else{
                    out.println(found.getName());
                }
                System.out.println("Printed " + found.getName());
            }
            out.println("ENDOFLIST"); //Notify the client it has to stop receiving data
```

For some reason, this outputs quite a lot of directories that I can't seem to find, even with the "Show hidden folders" option on.

When trying to access these directories, it tries to read the contents of the directory, but since the directory doesn't exist it throws an exception, causing no data to get sent over sockets and my client freezing.

My question is: Is there a way to either check if the file/directory REALLY exists? Note, if you look at my code block, if the file/dir doesn't exist it already continues instead of writing it to the socket.

I've given it a google, but no matches were found. Also, I've given the search function a go, but it didn't come up with anything similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the new Fil I/O API introduced by Java 7, it features greatly improved support of the features a specific file system offers. It also offers the possibility to use walk the file tree.

Have a look at the `FileVisitor` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileVisitor.html that will greatly help you.

Comment: How exactely would I check if it's a system folder?

Comment: How exactely do I check if it's a system folder? I did see BasicFileAtrributes' isRegularFile(), and isDirectory(), but not isSystemFile or something similar.

Comment: Have a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/DosFileAttributes.html Since you are operating on a NTFS. It has an `isSystem()` method.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, it seems to loop through all subdirectories aswell, although I only want the current directories content. I could do this by using my old loop and checking it for each file, but is there a way to do it "the new way"?

Comment: Implement the `preVisitDirectory` to return `SKIP_SUBTREE`. That tells the walker that you aren't interested in this subtree. I am not sure, maybe you have to check first if the current Directory is the one you want then you have to return `CONTINUE` for the one you want and `SKIP_SUBTREE` for those you don't want.

Comment: And if that answers your problem I would be greateful if you could formally "accept" my answer.

Comment: You can see an example of attributes based filtering in [here](http://blog.eyallupu.com/2011/11/java-7-working-with-directories.html) - the example filters on the file owner but you can take it from there.

Answer (score 3):

These are hidden *system* folders.
They do exist.  Really.

You get exceptions because a lot of them don't have read access.

Comment: But why can't I find them in Windows Explorer then? I'm using Windows 7, if that makes any difference.

Comment: @Lolmewn: Try enabling the "show system files" option in Windows Explorer, near the option to show hidden files.

Comment: See my answer below. Just walk the file tree and check the properties of the Folder, if it is a system folder.